# Angular get object from array by Id

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have an array:

```
this.questions = [
      {id: 1, question: "Do you feel a connection to a higher source and have a sense of comfort knowing that you are part of something greater than yourself?", category: "Spiritual", subs: []},
      {id: 2, question: "Do you feel you are free of unhealthy behavior that impacts your overall well-being?", category: "Habits", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 4, question: "Do you feel you have a sense of purpose and that you have a positive outlook about yourself and life?", category: "Emotional Well-being", subs: []},
      {id: 5, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy diet and that you are fueling your body for optimal health? ", category: "Eating Habits ", subs: []},
      {id: 6, question: "Do you feel that you get enough rest and that your stress level is healthy?", category: "Relaxation ", subs: []},
      {id: 7, question: "Do you feel you get enough physical activity for optimal health?", category: "Exercise ", subs: []},
      {id: 8, question: "Do you feel you practice self-care and go to the doctor regularly?", category: "Medical Maintenance", subs: []},
      {id: 9, question: "Do you feel satisfied with your income and economic stability?", category: "Financial", subs: []},
      {id: 10, question: "Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
      {id: 11, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy sense of balance in this area of your life?", category: "Work-life Balance", subs: []},
      {id: 12, question: "Do you feel a sense of peace and contentment  in your home? ", category: "Home Environment", subs: []},
      {id: 13, question: "Do you feel that you are challenged and growing as a person?", category: "Intellectual Wellbeing", subs: []},
      {id: 14, question: "Do you feel content with what you see when you look in the mirror?", category: "Self-image", subs: []},
      {id: 15, question: "Do you feel engaged at work and a sense of fulfillment with your job?", category: "Work Satisfaction", subs: []}

    ];
```

I have a function:

```
getDimensions(id) {    
   //need logic to get object from questions array based on ID.      
}
```

How can I write a map to get the correct object form the array based on ID?

Comment: `var result = this.questions.find(o => o.id === 10);`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use [**.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [**.find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). One difference that `filter` will iterate over all items and returns any which passes the condition as array while `find` will return the first matched item and break the iteration.

Example

```js
var questions = [
      {id: 1, question: "Do you feel a connection to a higher source and have a sense of comfort knowing that you are part of something greater than yourself?", category: "Spiritual", subs: []},
      {id: 2, question: "Do you feel you are free of unhealthy behavior that impacts your overall well-being?", category: "Habits", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 4, question: "Do you feel you have a sense of purpose and that you have a positive outlook about yourself and life?", category: "Emotional Well-being", subs: []},
      {id: 5, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy diet and that you are fueling your body for optimal health? ", category: "Eating Habits ", subs: []},
      {id: 6, question: "Do you feel that you get enough rest and that your stress level is healthy?", category: "Relaxation ", subs: []},
      {id: 7, question: "Do you feel you get enough physical activity for optimal health?", category: "Exercise ", subs: []},
      {id: 8, question: "Do you feel you practice self-care and go to the doctor regularly?", category: "Medical Maintenance", subs: []},
      {id: 9, question: "Do you feel satisfied with your income and economic stability?", category: "Financial", subs: []},
      {id: 10, question: "Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
      {id: 11, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy sense of balance in this area of your life?", category: "Work-life Balance", subs: []},
      {id: 12, question: "Do you feel a sense of peace and contentment  in your home? ", category: "Home Environment", subs: []},
      {id: 13, question: "Do you feel that you are challenged and growing as a person?", category: "Intellectual Wellbeing", subs: []},
      {id: 14, question: "Do you feel content with what you see when you look in the mirror?", category: "Self-image", subs: []},
      {id: 15, question: "Do you feel engaged at work and a sense of fulfillment with your job?", category: "Work Satisfaction", subs: []}
];

function getDimensionsByFilter(id){
  return questions.filter(x => x.id === id);
}

function getDimensionsByFind(id){
  return questions.find(x => x.id === id);
}

var test = getDimensionsByFilter(10);
console.log(test);

test = getDimensionsByFind(10);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: @JudsonTerrell: If the answer helped you, it is better to mark it as accepted, it give you point, give the answerer points, help people with the same problem finding the answer :)

Answer (score 9):

```
getDimensions(id) {
    var obj = questions.filter(function(node) {
        return node.id==id;
    });

    return obj;   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**CASE - 1**

Using **`array.filter()`** We can get an array of objects which will match with our condition.
see the working example.

```js
var questions = [
      {id: 1, question: "Do you feel a connection to a higher source and have a sense of comfort knowing that you are part of something greater than yourself?", category: "Spiritual", subs: []},
      {id: 2, question: "Do you feel you are free of unhealthy behavior that impacts your overall well-being?", category: "Habits", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "1 Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "2 Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "3 Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 4, question: "Do you feel you have a sense of purpose and that you have a positive outlook about yourself and life?", category: "Emotional Well-being", subs: []},
      {id: 5, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy diet and that you are fueling your body for optimal health? ", category: "Eating Habits ", subs: []},
      {id: 6, question: "Do you feel that you get enough rest and that your stress level is healthy?", category: "Relaxation ", subs: []},
      {id: 7, question: "Do you feel you get enough physical activity for optimal health?", category: "Exercise ", subs: []},
      {id: 8, question: "Do you feel you practice self-care and go to the doctor regularly?", category: "Medical Maintenance", subs: []},
      {id: 9, question: "Do you feel satisfied with your income and economic stability?", category: "Financial", subs: []},
      {id: 10, question: "1 Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
      {id: 10, question: "2 Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
      {id: 11, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy sense of balance in this area of your life?", category: "Work-life Balance", subs: []},
      {id: 12, question: "Do you feel a sense of peace and contentment  in your home? ", category: "Home Environment", subs: []},
      {id: 13, question: "Do you feel that you are challenged and growing as a person?", category: "Intellectual Wellbeing", subs: []},
      {id: 14, question: "Do you feel content with what you see when you look in the mirror?", category: "Self-image", subs: []},
      {id: 15, question: "Do you feel engaged at work and a sense of fulfillment with your job?", category: "Work Satisfaction", subs: []}
];

function filter(){
  console.clear();
  var filter_id = document.getElementById("filter").value;
  var filter_array = questions.filter(x => x.id == filter_id);
  console.log(filter_array);
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="filter"></label>
  <input id="filter" type="number" name="filter" placeholder="Enter id which you want to filter">
  <button onclick="filter()">Filter</button>
</div>
```

**CASE - 2**

Using **`array.find()`** we can get first matched item and break the iteration.

```js
var questions = [
      {id: 1, question: "Do you feel a connection to a higher source and have a sense of comfort knowing that you are part of something greater than yourself?", category: "Spiritual", subs: []},
      {id: 2, question: "Do you feel you are free of unhealthy behavior that impacts your overall well-being?", category: "Habits", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "1 Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "2 Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 3, question: "3 Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
      {id: 4, question: "Do you feel you have a sense of purpose and that you have a positive outlook about yourself and life?", category: "Emotional Well-being", subs: []},
      {id: 5, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy diet and that you are fueling your body for optimal health? ", category: "Eating Habits ", subs: []},
      {id: 6, question: "Do you feel that you get enough rest and that your stress level is healthy?", category: "Relaxation ", subs: []},
      {id: 7, question: "Do you feel you get enough physical activity for optimal health?", category: "Exercise ", subs: []},
      {id: 8, question: "Do you feel you practice self-care and go to the doctor regularly?", category: "Medical Maintenance", subs: []},
      {id: 9, question: "Do you feel satisfied with your income and economic stability?", category: "Financial", subs: []},
      {id: 10, question: "1 Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
      {id: 10, question: "2 Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
      {id: 11, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy sense of balance in this area of your life?", category: "Work-life Balance", subs: []},
      {id: 12, question: "Do you feel a sense of peace and contentment  in your home? ", category: "Home Environment", subs: []},
      {id: 13, question: "Do you feel that you are challenged and growing as a person?", category: "Intellectual Wellbeing", subs: []},
      {id: 14, question: "Do you feel content with what you see when you look in the mirror?", category: "Self-image", subs: []},
      {id: 15, question: "Do you feel engaged at work and a sense of fulfillment with your job?", category: "Work Satisfaction", subs: []}
];

function find(){
  console.clear();
  var find_id = document.getElementById("find").value;
  var find_object = questions.find(x => x.id == find_id);
  console.log(find_object);
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="find"></label>
  <input id="find" type="number" name="find" placeholder="Enter id which you want to find">
  <button onclick="find()">Find</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Used In TypeScript For Angular 4+        
const viewArray = [
          {id: 1, question: "Do you feel a connection to a higher source and have a sense of comfort knowing that you are part of something greater than yourself?", category: "Spiritual", subs: []},
          {id: 2, question: "Do you feel you are free of unhealthy behavior that impacts your overall well-being?", category: "Habits", subs: []},
          {id: 3, question: "Do you feel you have healthy and fulfilling relationships?", category: "Relationships", subs: []},
          {id: 4, question: "Do you feel you have a sense of purpose and that you have a positive outlook about yourself and life?", category: "Emotional Well-being", subs: []},
          {id: 5, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy diet and that you are fueling your body for optimal health? ", category: "Eating Habits ", subs: []},
          {id: 6, question: "Do you feel that you get enough rest and that your stress level is healthy?", category: "Relaxation ", subs: []},
          {id: 7, question: "Do you feel you get enough physical activity for optimal health?", category: "Exercise ", subs: []},
          {id: 8, question: "Do you feel you practice self-care and go to the doctor regularly?", category: "Medical Maintenance", subs: []},
          {id: 9, question: "Do you feel satisfied with your income and economic stability?", category: "Financial", subs: []},
          {id: 10, question: "Do you feel you do fun things and laugh enough in your life?", category: "Play", subs: []},
          {id: 11, question: "Do you feel you have a healthy sense of balance in this area of your life?", category: "Work-life Balance", subs: []},
          {id: 12, question: "Do you feel a sense of peace and contentment  in your home? ", category: "Home Environment", subs: []},
          {id: 13, question: "Do you feel that you are challenged and growing as a person?", category: "Intellectual Wellbeing", subs: []},
          {id: 14, question: "Do you feel content with what you see when you look in the mirror?", category: "Self-image", subs: []},
          {id: 15, question: "Do you feel engaged at work and a sense of fulfillment with your job?", category: "Work Satisfaction", subs: []}
    ];

         const arrayObj = any;
         const objectData = any;

          for (let index = 0; index < this.viewArray.length; index++) {
              this.arrayObj = this.viewArray[index];
              this.arrayObj.filter((x) => {
                if (x.id === id) {
                  this.objectData = x;
                }
              });
              console.log('Json Object Data by ID ==> ', this.objectData);
            }
          };
```